# What's the `biblatex` capacity?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies, biber

I'm reading the `biblatex`package documentation. In fact, the table 4 describes the reference size capacities of `bibtex8` but never give us a comparison or data about the `biber` capacity and I want to know if there is information about it in a similar way as the table described below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`texdoc biber`:

> 2.6. Performance
>
> Biber can’t really be compared with BIBTEX in any meaningful way performance- wise. Biber is written in Perl and does a
> great deal more than BIBTEX which is written in C. One of Biber’s test
> cases is a 2150 entry, 15,000 line .bib file which references a 630
> entry macros file with a resulting 160 or so page (A4) formatted
> bibliography. This takes Biber under 3 minutes to process on a
> reasonable computer. This is perfectly acceptable, especially for a
> batch program.